# Is router a facade pattern?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles, facade

I have this router class, but I am not sure what pattern it should belongs to. It seems to be a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) or mediator pattern to me. What do you think?

```
class Router 
{
...
}
```

usage,

```
$router = new Router();

$router->get('/', function() { ... });
$router->get('foo/', function() { ... });
$router->post('foo/', function() { ... });
```

But then, it seems that it is said that router is an anti-pattern as some of the commets suggest in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015568/a-software-design-issue-the-router-class). if router is violating patterns, then what are the solutions?

Answer (score 1):

A router is not a pattern itself, its just a tool, which merely matches URI string against known *reg-ex patterns*. And once a match is found, then controller's instantiation needs to be handled by another tool, which is known as *Dispatcher*. So there's a clean separation between responsibilities, thus adhering to *Single-Responsibility Principle*.

A router itself doesn't violate any known pattern. Only you might violate them when writing a router class.

To launch your application, you also need to implement things like Front Controller, Dispatcher, and PSR-0 class autoloader.

As for facades, your router implementation has nothing to do with it. Because facades aren't meant for such things. Taylor calls facades classes, which provide services, it's not a facade pattern implementation.

A facade itself is just a wrapper, which must have one interface for different environments. For example, a very popular example of Facade implementation in JavaScript

```
function click(elem, event, callback){
  if (elem.addEventListener != undefined){
     return elem.addEventListener(..);
  } else if (elem.attachEvent != undefined) {
     return elem.attachEvent(..);
  } else {
     return elem.onclick = callback;
  }
}
```

Or maybe that could be something like this:

```
// For old PHP versions
if (!function_exists('file_get_contents')){
  function file_get_contents(){
    // ...
  }
}
```

That's what facades are all about.

And finally to answer your question,
I'd say, that you should stop thinking about how to write a perfect code if you don't know how router should work. You'd better start writing what works, and then start thinking about improvements of it. As a result, you might get good and working code.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but `Only you might violate them when writing a router class.` - why shouldn't make a router a class? it should be just a function then?

Comment: When I wrote that sentence, I meant, that many developers abuse route implementation by putting everything into it. Their router knows too much a does too much, i.e you can see dispatcher's and front controller's implementation there in one class.

Answer (score 0):

A router can be part of a Facade. As an example the front of a building is a facade. You can't see what's behind it but the front of the building is real. You can make a set of controllers that form a facade. Of course the controllers needs routes. So together they form the facade. The set is divided by parts. One part of the set you look at is "User". Everything related to users is behind "User". That way "User" acts as the facade. In that way you can aggregate user related stuff in a facade.